Avalonia Binding not updating
why is my binding not working correctly, its grabbing the value once but never updating
after this.RaisPropertyChanged...
public ScreenViewModel Screen => screen;
public bool SetScreen(ScreenViewModel screen) => Notify(ref this.screen, screen, false, nameof(Screen));
{
  field = value;
  Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => this.RaisePropertyChanged(name));
}

<DataTemplate x:Key="applicationscreenmaintemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type vm:ApplicationScreenViewModel}">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewManager.Screen, Mode=OneWay}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource screenselector}"/>
</DataTemplate>


Not 100% sure but it's probably because you are invoking the PropertyChanged event on the dispatcher.  Raising and event doesn't modify a UI object, so there is no need to do that.  If that doesn't work, I'd need to see more about where you are calling SetScreen()

yea the dispatcher call is for reactive ui had some issues with that ...

solved... not sure why but the contentpresenter was not working as expected -> using contentcontrol instead !
